# AFNetworking with CLLocation gives error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation, afnetworking-3

I am working with AFNetworking 3.0 and CLLocation for weather app.

When I click on button, API must have to update with location. But It gives me error after updating location.

I am using **world weather** api for getting weather details.

The **error** is,

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011
>   "Request failed: forbidden (403)"
>   UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL:
>   http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?format=json&key=1b8c4f157aec499cba0120254161609&num_of_days=5&q=19.017615%2C72.856164 } { status code: 403, headers {
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
>       Age = 0;
>       "Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=120";
>       Connection = "keep-alive";
>       "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
>       "Content-Length" = 96;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Mon, 19 Sep 2016 05:53:12 GMT";
>       Expires = "Mon, 19 Sep 2016 05:55:13 GMT";
>       Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
>       Via = WebCelerate;
>       "X-Cache" = MISS;
>       "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
>       "X-Webcelerate" = "WebCelerate - www.ukfast.co.uk/web-acceleration.html";
>       "X-node" = "zfdl_api_01";
>       "access-control-allow-headers" = "content-type"; } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?format=json&key=1b8c4f157aec499cba0120254161609&num_of_days=5&q=19.017615%2C72.856164,
>   com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b202264 61746122
>   3a207b20 22657272 6f72223a 205b207b 226d7367 223a2022 41504920
>   6b657920 646f6573 206e6f74 20686176 65206163 63657373 20746f20
>   74686520 7265736f 75726365 2e22207d 205d207d 7d>,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403)}

I have refer all the articles on net but cannot find the proper answer for this.

I have some methods for perform this functionality,

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{NSLog(@"location updated");
    // Last object contains the most recent location
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    // If the location is more than 5 minutes old, ignore it
    if([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow] > 300)
        return;

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    WeatherHTTPClient *client = [WeatherHTTPClient sharedWeatherHTTPClient];
    client.delegate = self;
    [client updateWeatherAtLocation:newLocation forNumberOfDays:5];
}

- (void)weatherHTTPClient:(WeatherHTTPClient *)client didUpdateWithWeather:(id)weather
{
    self.weather = weather;
    self.title = @"API Updated";
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"API updated");
}

- (void)weatherHTTPClient:(WeatherHTTPClient *)client didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    NSLog(@"error - %@", error);
}
```

This methods call when I tapped button named API. And updating locations and give the data in tableview. But its not working.

Button method is :

```
- (IBAction)apiTapped:(id)sender
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"apiTapped");
}
```

I am refering this tutorial for AFNetworking demo,

https://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

As per that tutorial everything is working fine for them in AFNetworking 2.0 but not form me.

So what is the issue in my code?

Comment: if your server is ssl certified please use https instead of http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

The problem is with access. I have account in world weather with free user. and the api url is ,

> http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/

So with free acount they not providing some access to their api.

I changed the url to,

> http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/

So now they are allowing to access the api and the error is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

Your client received `HTTP Error 403 Forbidden` that means

> The request was a valid request, but the server is refusing to respond
>   to it. The user might be logged in but does not have the necessary
>   permissions for the resource.

So check you authorization status. For more info please look the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403